# How to create code signing and IPA-file in xcode4.3?

Tags: xcode4.3, ipa, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I'm building my first app in xcode4.3 on lion. Now I want to beta-test using testflight. I've looked at the tutorial: 
"http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-"
But I get stuck at the 2nd step when I'm about to create an Entitlement. In xcode I don't have the "code signing" alternative in the "IOS" template list and am unable to continue the guide. And all the other tutorials I've found are outdated. I would really appreciate a step-by-step guide that works with xcode4.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the Entitlements file, you can do like this:

Click your project, then Targets- Summary, at then end you can see 'Enable Entitlements', check it then you can see a new file named yourApp.Entitlements appeared in your project.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is outdated, with xcode 4.3 you dont create an ipa and upload with uploader as in that tutorial.  Create your app ID, code sign, and you will be asked during the process whether you want to distribute to Appstore or create ipa.  Just follow the process and you will be presented with that option towards the end, then you can create your IPA